# Most concise way to write this query to add hour to a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field with a DateTime.  I want to ignore the time on that field and add a specified hour.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for, where @h could be any value from 0 to 23. (And I'm using getdate() instead of the field from my table for simplicity here).

```
declare @h int = 8
select cast(cast(cast(getdate() as date) as nvarchar(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@h as nvarchar(2)) + ':00' as datetime)
```

How can I write this more simply?  Keeping in mind that I'm more interested in readability/maintainability than speed here.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? 2005 or 2008?

Comment: Has to be 2008 if he is using `DATE` datatype...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT DATEADD(hour, 1, CAST((CAST (GETDATE() as DATE)) as datetime))`

You can put a parameter in place of the `1` here as needed.

Comment: Crazy... I actually tried that first (I thought) but got an error that made it sound like DATEADD didn't support adding hours.  Your statement clearly works though so +1.

Comment: You have to convert to `DATETIME` before adding.  `DATE` datatype doesn't support hours.

Comment: Ah.  Actually I did try that too, but I had the arguments out of order and forgot to cast again when I fixed that part.  Wednesdays are basically my Mondays though so I blame it on that.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
declare @h int = 8
select dateadd(hh, @h, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

Comment: @JNK  Hey, maybe he's just a slow typer.  I'll give him the benefit of the doubt :)